# How to update only gridjs record not whole table when attribute changes inside the data in gridjs-react

Tags: gridjs, gridjs-react

How to update only gridjs record not whole table when attribute changes inside the data in gridjs-react

I am have added a checkbox as a viurtual dom. when I select the checkbox into 2nd or 3rd page
it is rerending the whole table and coming back again on first page.

how to handle this